# IONIC: unable to get values out of the `$http` within `$ionicPlatform.on` method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic1 framework and working on sidemenu ionic app.    I am using `cordova local notification` its working fine but  i need to send notification on specific condition within `$ionicPlatform.ready`.   For condition, i am getting data from webservice using  `$http` but unfortunately i am unable to retrieve data out of the `$http`.

```
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
 var conditionvariable="true";

 $http.get("http://www.example.com/abc.php").then(function(response) 
   {
       var test = response.data[0];
        if(test.result=='test')
                {
                     conditionvariable="false";
                 }   
    });

  alert(conditionvariable);
 })
```

I am unable to get data out of the function `$http.get` function.   If i am trying to alert it out of the function it alerts `undefined`

Please help how to get data.

Comment: This has been asked (and answered) at least a thousand times on Stackoverflow alone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

This is because $http is an asynchronous call and then() is called when the response from http call will be available,
and your alert() is executed synchronously before the response is available from the network call.

read in detail here
[Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
 var conditionvariable="true";

 $http.get("http://www.example.com/abc.php").then(function(response) 
   {
       var test = response.data[0];
        if(test.result=='test')
                {
                     conditionvariable="false";
                 }  
    alert(conditionvariable);

    });
})
```

now your alert runs when you get the response from the $http call.

hope this helps...

Comment: thank you @mahiraj2709 for the reply...I have tried Asynchronous code reference but no luck i just want value out of the `$http.get` function

Comment: why don't you put your alert inside the then returned by the promise..$http.get("http://www.example.com/abc.php").then(function(response) 
   {
       var test = response.data[0];
        if(test.result=='test')
                {
                     conditionvariable="false";
                 }   
alert(conditionvariable);
    });

Comment: I have to take value outside the promise that's why i alert this outside